# Selenium Chromedriver : How to open a specific Chrome profile

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**I want Selenium to open and control one of my existing Chrome profile named `Selenium`**. I've tried different solutions but none of them work.

Profile name : `Selenium`

Profile directory : `Profile 5`

**1- First I've tried** :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:/Users/raphg/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data')
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 5')
```

This opens the right chrome profile but in a Chrome window that is not controlled by Selenium. Plus, my script crashes with the error : `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument`

**2- Then I've tried to clone the profile directory and to reference it like this** :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:/Users/path_where_I_put_the_directory') 
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 5')
```

This time, it gives me no crashes, but this opens a Chrome profile that is like a clone of my `Selenium` profile and it is not connected to my Google account unlike the real one.

With images, [real profile](https://ibb.co/7CC2WQQ) VS [the clone](https://ibb.co/J5jNT1B) :

Comment: Try using "--user-data-dir=" (include the beginning dashes)

Comment: @LukeHamilton No, unfortunatly, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

In short: **you need to clone the entire 'User Data' folder, not just the profile you'll be using**.

Here were the problems:

- For the first solution I've tried, the error I got (`user data directory is already in use`) speaks for itself, I couldn't use any profiles if I had already a profil in use. Here I was using 'Default' (for browsing purpose) so using any profile in `User Data` folder with Selenium would give this error.
- That brings us to the second solution I've tried : moving the profile I needed to another location. The reason Selenium webdriver opened like a clone of my profile was because **it was missing some files from the 'User Data' folder.**

So to solve this:

1- Go to `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome` and copy the 'User Data' folder

2- Paste it to wherever you want (let's say to `C:/Users/my_scripts`. So now you have `C:/Users/my_scripts/User Data`)

3- Use the profile you want with Selenium

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:/Users/my_scripts/User Data') 
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Default')
# Or
options.add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 5')
```